# Implementing IF condition in a map function spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
val keyValue = parsedData.map(x => (x.col1,x.col2,
  if(x.col3 = "a") "0.1" 
  else if(x.col3 = "b") "0.2" 
  else if(x.col3 = "c") "0.3" 
  else if(x.col3 = "d") "0.4"     
  else if(x.col3 = "e") "0.5"))
```

My parsedData rdd has 3 columns and for my third column i am trying to do the above, and you might have guessed its not working.

Any ideas how to implement this ?

Comment: What error are you getting? This looks valid to me. The only thing I notice is that you'll end up with a Unit type for the last column since you have no else

Comment: what's the type of x ?

Comment: Its saying expression of type unit doesn't conform to expected type boolean. parsedData has data like (1,2,a),(2,3,b),(3,4,c)

Comment: still doesn't answer my question, what is the type of x? can you run :type parsedData if you are using spark-shell?

Comment: its an rdd, I am not sure if I am missing something ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems:

1. You should be using `==` instead of `=`
2. You need an `else` or else your type for the 3rd item will be Unit...but that will still compile. Worst case, you should maybe use an `Option`?

Comment: You could also use a `match` to be more concise. `x.col3 match { case "a" => "0.1" case "b" => "0.2" ... }`